# Cannot get attributes of jquery XMLDocument

Tags: jquery

From what I can tell I should be able to get an attribute from an xml doucment using the attr() function? If so then why do the two lines below return me undefined. I have added them to the sample code on the jquery documentation for parseXML() at: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

```
console.log("Attributes: " + $xml.attributes);
console.log("Attr: " + $xml.attr('version'));
```

Full page is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery.parseXML demo</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="someElement"></p>
<p id="anotherElement"></p>
<script>
var xml = $.parseXML("<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>");
console.log("Attributes: " + $(xml).attributes);
console.log("Attr: " + $(xml).attr('version'));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It probably doesn't help that you have commas, instead of semi-colons after your statements starting at the xml variable.

Comment: It is syntactically correct. Taken straight from the Jquery website. That part is not the issue. I added the two console.log() statements and nothing more.

Comment: even if it is technically correct, it's confusing. why would you do it?

Comment: I didn't do it. That's from the original example on the Jquery page for which there is a link above. I just want to read an attribute from an xml node and it does not work. That is my issue.

Comment: I have modified the original sample to make things more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the XML Document object does not support these operations. Documentation on this type of object is very vague. But replacing

```
$.parseXML("<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>");
```

with

```
$("<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>");
```

overcomes the problem